# Can't connect MongoDB in Windows Server 2008 sometimes

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My  MongoDB service is running in Windows Server 2008 R2, but when I am trying to connect or access data it throws an error like "unable to connect" or "invalid access".
These issues happen sometimes; if I restart the service again it works normal.
How to fix this issue?